# Java 8: How to get particular value within object inside list without converting stream back to list and fetch value at 0th location?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I need to return value from `href()` inside a list of links where Rel value is `String`.

```
class Links{
    String rel;
    String href;
 }

class 2{
    List<Links> links
 }
```

Following code is doing so but it is not looking cool

```
return links.stream().filter(d -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(d.getRel(), "Self")).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0).getHref();
```

Is there any way to fetch `getHref` directly from list in place of `converting it back to list` and `get 0th element`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `findFirst()`:

```
return links.stream()
            .filter(d -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(d.getRel(), "Self"))
            .findFirst() // returns an Optional<Links>
            .map(Links::getHref) // returns an Optional<String>
            .orElse(null); // returns String (either getHref of the found Links instance, or
                           // null if no instance passed the filter)
```

Comment: Thanks...Return type optional ? Eclipse is picking String

Comment: @fatherazrael `orElse(null)` would return `String`.

Comment: I recommend replacing `.filter(d -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(d.getRel(), "Self"))` with `.filter(d -> "Self".equalsIgnoreCase(d.getRel()))`, as then, the reader doesn't have to guess, which obsolete 3rd party library has been used.